# RIP Anne Rice - Interview with the Vampire

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Anne Rice has passed away at 80. I loved the *Interview with the Vampire* series when I was a teen, and I loved the movie back when Tom Cruise wasn't nutty and Brad Pitt was new to Hollywood. Anyhow, the series was formative for me, and tons of other girls too. As a newbie to any fandom, I didn't realize the *Vampire* series was problematic to girls - I just saw it as entertainment.

[image: Image of Claudia with the caption, "Who will take care of me, my love, my dark angel, when you are gone?"]

Notorious for being one of the authors who forbade, and tried to legally bar, fan fiction of her work, [Anne Rice softened her position in later years](https://metro.co.uk/2012/11/11/how-fan-fiction-is-conquering-the-internet-and-shooting-up-book-charts-617396/).

> "I got upset about 20 years ago because I thought it would block me," she said. "However, it’s been very easy to avoid reading any, so live and let live. If I were a young writer, I’d want to own my own ideas. But maybe fan fiction is a transitional phase: whatever gets you there, gets you there.

Comment: Wouldn't her estate have something to say about fanfic?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Just to be sure, "tried to legally bar", do you mean "tried to legally ban"?

Comment: Both are valid statements. "Bar" can also mean "prevent".